# es6ify.runtime makes my THREE js importing empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, ecmascript-6, traceur

I am trying to browserify javascript es6 code with es6ify.
My code is using THREE js library (a webgl abstraction library), and everything works pretty well until I try to add the traceur compiler runtime at the top of the bundle.

Here is my gulp task (the problem mustn't be related to gulp):

```
gulp.task('build', function(){

    browserify({debug: true})
    .add(es6ify.runtime)
    .transform(es6ify)
    .require(require.resolve('./app/index.js'), {entry: true})
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/'));

});
```

somewhere in my application, I am trying to do something like:

```
import THREE from 'three';

var toto = new THREE.WebGLRenderer([...]);
```

and this **fails** because `THREE` is actualy an **empty object**, thus `WebGLRenderer` is undefined.

THREE js is in the dependencies of node package.json, and THREE JS is **usually imported well**. But when I add `add(es6ify.runtime)` in my build process, it causes `require('three')` to be an empty object...

is there something I missed?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

well, sorry for the inconvenience, I just found a solution.
If I simply exclude the node modules from traceur compilation, it works:

so instead of:

```
.transform(es6ify)
```

I have now:

```
.transform(es6ify.configure(/^(?!.*node_modules)+.+\.js$/))
```

(this is [an es6ifyAPI documentation](https://github.com/thlorenz/es6ify) sample)

which is by the way faster to compile :-)